# how to cut a string using length in unix shell

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, cut

### Edited

I have a problem in finding a pattern in a string. Actually i want to compare two files and replace content of file1 to file 2 having the below content

#### File1

`000123   moorsevi har      NC asee    terel`
`000125   staevil strd      NC klass   aklsd`
`000126   carolie asdr      NC skdkld  kaks`
`000128   histvil df        NC lllas   kasd`

#### File2

`000123   moorsevile har    NC asee    terel`
`000125   staevile strd     NC klass   aklsd`
`000126   caroline asdr     CA skdkld  kaks`

Here i have to match first column and replace the column 2&3 in file2, where length of the line in file2 should not changed.

i have tried with the below code.

```
#! /bin/ksh
IFS=$
ite=0
while read -r line
do
    seqno=$(echo $line|cut -c1-9)
    add=$(echo $line |cut -c10-28)
    state=$(echo $line|cut -c29-31)
    echo "seq no:[$seqno] add:[$add] state:[$state]"
    line1=$(grep $seqno file1)
    add1=$(echo $line1|cut -c10-28)
    state1=$(echo $line1|cut -c29-31)

    echo "on file 1 address:[$add1]: state:[$state1]"

    sed -e "s/$add/$add1/g" -e "s/$state/$state1/g" file2 |tee file2

    ite=`expr $ite + 1`
    echo "iteration= $ite"
done <file2
IFS="\n"
echo "IFS:[$IFS]"
```

#### Expected Output:

#### File2

`000123   moorsevi har      NC asee    terel`
`000125   staevil strd      NC klass   aklsd`
`000126   carolie asdr      NC skdkld  kaks`

Shell experts in this forum conveyed that using awk is the right way

show me some light on achieving the solution using awk.

Comment: Oh no. `string=12345678` if you want `1234` it is `newstring=${string:0:4}`. It is called using *string indexes*. If you just want to cut string down, then `string=${string:0:4}`

Comment: Your post is very unclear. You write to cut length 6 but take 4 character, then 13 from a 5 "field" string and expected result show those field (and not a length defined separator/structure). What do you really want ? reading expected result i propose `echo "${line}" | read seqno add state Ignore` that you can use in the loop scope

Comment: I'm having problem with the markdown @NeronLeVelu."123<spaces>moorsevile<4space>NC<1space>asee<space>    terel" this is the first line available in the file. In expected output: it is seq no:123<3space> add:Moorsevile     S.....

Comment: This is the problem actual line has 3 space after 123 but when i print the variable line it is delimited with single space

Comment: Thank u @DavidC.Rankin slicing is wat i expect. i thought it is python funtionality

Comment: Glad I could help. Just note it only works in bash, zsh, etc.. It does not work in the old bourne shell or in POSIX shell.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin. so sad i need this functionality in ksh. is there any alternative for this?

Comment: Should also work in ksh, just check the shell manual. (it may be slightly different syntax) All of the more recent shells support string indexes.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i'm using ksh88 it doesn't support slicing. any other way ??

Comment: Yes, you can use the POSIX `expr substr string start length` expression. Again `string=12345678` and you want `1234`, so you do `newstr=$(expr substr "$string" 1 4)` and you get `newstr=1234`. Using the `expr stuff` expressions are just a lot slower than the newer builtin string indexes in other shells.

Comment: Sorry to bug u @DavidC.Rankin `substr` will handle only word not complete line of string in my prob string variable hold `123   Mooersevile` it is throwing an error `expr: An integer value was expected.`

Comment: You are using the completely wrong tool - shell is NOT for manipulating text which is why it's so difficult to do it in shell. To manipulate text, shell just calls awk, that is all, and the end result will be briefer, clearer, faster, more robust, more portable and in every other way better than if you tried to force shell to do it.

Comment: Just say some of your comments above and in response: If your real input contains 3 spaces, put 3 spaces in the sample. If your expected output contains 3 spaces, put 3 spaces in the sample. If awk `is throwing error when i use $@` then show the command you are executing and the error message being produced. In general - don't show us stuff that doesn't exist in your real files and ask us to help you write a script to work on them, nor ask us to help debug scripts without showing us the script and the actual error message.

Comment: @EdMorton I have updated the query. Sorry that i don't know markdown will trimm multiple spaces in to one. so this confusion happens.Also i have tried this command `seqno=$(echo $line|awk '{print substr($@,1,6)}')` and i got this error message `The error context is
                {print >>>  substr($@ <<<
 awk: The statement cannot be correctly parsed.
 The source line is 1.` correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Awk has no idea what `$@` is. I think you meant `$0`. But again - your approach in trying to use shell to manipulate text is 100% wrong so correcting stuff like that is like showing you the right way to hold a spoon when you're trying to carve a turkey with it.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for opening my eyes. i'm completely new to awk can u please help me in getting the problem done with awk

Comment: I posted an answer containing 2 awk scripts, both of which would produce the output you want. One uses multiple spaces as the delimiter, the other uses fixed field positions. Have you tried them? Do either of them not do what you want and, if so, what is it they are doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your new requirements, is this what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS="9 18 11 5" }
NR==FNR { f2[$1]=$2; f3[$1]=$3; next }
$1 in f2 { print $1 f2[$1] f3[$1] $4 $5 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
000123   moorsevi har      NC asee    terel
000125   staevil strd      NC klass   aklsd
000126   carolie asdr      NC skdkld  kaks
```

Uses GNU awk for `FIELDWIDTHS`.

Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: wow awk is much powerful.  still i got output like this ``000123moorseviharNCasee``
``000125staevilstrdNCklass``
``000126carolieasdrCAskdkld``
i can understand ur logic too but i don't know why it is not printed with field width which u mentioned.

Comment: Because you aren't using GNU awk so setting FIELDWIDTHS is having no effect. Get GNU awk.

Answer (score 0):

You're just extracting fields in a delimited text.  It's a standard use case for `awk`.  For example

```
$ echo "123 moorsevile NC asee terel" | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'

123 moorsevile NC
```

to add the relevant tags

```
 ... | awk '{print "seq no:"$1, "add:"$2, "state:"$3}'
```

seq no:123 add:moorsevile state:NC

or initial caps of the city

```
awk '{print "seq no:" $1,"add:" toupper(substr($2,1,1)) substr($2,2), "state:" $3}'

seq no:123 add:Moorsevile state:NC
```

or any arbitrary field delimiter in the output

```
awk -v OFS=" ~ " '{print "seq no:" $1,
     "add:" toupper(substr($2,1,1)) substr($2,2) ,"state:" $3}'

seq no:123 ~ add:Moorsevile ~ state:NC
```

Comment: it is not a delimited text i have updated the query clearly. i have to extract the string based on character length @karakfa

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion now i have updated the query.here the mistake i have made is that IFS is set to space (`while IFS= read -r line`) so when i load the `line` variable with multiple space it is converted in to one. Below code is working as expected.

```
#! /bin/ksh
IFS=$
ite=0
while read -r line
do
#seqno=$(echo $line|awk '{print substr($0,1,6)}')
#add=$(echo $line |awk '{print substr($0,7,20)}')
#state=$(echo $line|awk '{print substr($0,21,23)}')
#echo "seq no:$seqno add:$add state:$state"
seqno=$(echo $line|cut -c1-6)
add=$(echo $line |cut -c7-20)
state=$(echo $line|cut -c21-23)
echo "seq no:$seqno add:$add state:$state"

ite=`expr $ite + 1`
echo "iteration= $ite"
done <file2
IFS="\n"
```

My output is
`seq no:123    add:moorsevile     state:NC
iteration= 1
seq no:125    add:staevile       state:NC
iteration= 2
seq no:126    add:caroline       state:CA
iteration= 3`

Thanks for all your help.
and my sincere apologies if i have wasted your time.

Comment: No! Your original script was using `IFS` correctly, this new one is messing it up. Your opening sentence above is completely wrong - `while IFS= read -r line` is NOT setting IFS to a space and it does NOT convert multiple spaces to 1. You are not listening to any of the advice you've been given, even the original misguided advice you got about how to do this in valid shell syntax.